# sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip showing error

Tags: 14.04, php7

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-zip : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2) but 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
```

Comment: Looks like you're out of date on your package data, try `sudo apt-get update` and then try and install?

Comment: Did you installed php7.0 ?

Comment: I have installed the php7.0 and the sudo apt-get update does not solve my problem